# Bloomberg API - Request type

Tags: bloomberg

How to identify whether to make ReferenceData request or Subscription(MarketData) request using Bloomberg API based on input fields.
I.e.. Based on Security and fields

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Please provide more information.

Comment: Apologies if my request was incomplete. We have a requirement where user will type only Security field name from our UI. We have to decide whether to make Realtime or RefData request.

Comment: Got response from Helpdesk just now. They are suggesting to use fieldSearchRequest.

Comment: @PrashanthG Feel free to post an answer if you manage to solve your issue. The list of "Subscription" fields in the developer guide is not necessarily up to date so doing a field search may indeed be the best option.

Comment: Helpdesk suggested to do following.
Make fieldSearchRequest with fieldType as "Static". If Response "does not contain" field name it means we need to do Realtime request. Hope I have answered/clarified :)
Eg:
service = session.getService("//blp/apiflds");
Request request = service.createRequest("fieldSearchRequest");
request.set("searchSpec",fieldName);
Element element = request.get("include");
element.setElement("fieldType","Static");

Comment: This isn't really a programming question - it's a question about Bloomberg requests...

Answer (score 1):

**ReferenceData** (`"//blp/refdata"`) is for static/historical/snapshot data. For example:

- descriptive data for a ticker & field
- historical tick/intraday/daily data for a ticker & field, which can be requested for today to get a current snapshot

**MarketData** (`"//blp/mktdata"`) is for real-time subscriptions. For example:

- rather than polling every interval for a value, you subscribe and get sent messages with updates.

Different fields are supported for reference data requests or market data subscriptions. In the Bloomberg Terminal, `FLDS` will show the different fields for a given ticker, and will indicate whether the field is for reference data or market data. For example, the reference data field for the last price is `PX_LAST`, whereas the market data field for the last price is `LAST_PRICE`.

If in doubt, you can always ask the live helpdesk to clarify whether a field is for reference data or market data. They have previously sent me a spreadsheet detailing the available API fields. However, I'm afraid I'm not able to share this - I only mention it as something you can ask for. But, be aware that this would only be a snapshot and the canonical reference is `FLDS`.

If you want to further understand the difference between reference data requests and market data subscriptions, I would suggest that you have a look at the examples that are included in the download from WAPI.

Comment: You have misprint in answer. Market data subscription use field "//blp/mktdata"